# Python appending Dataframe by external methods

Tags: python, pandas

In my project I have a **Strategy** which stores LOGS into a dataframe.
A **Strategy** is a succession of **Block** instances.
Each Block can writeLog().

What I want is that each block points to the Strategy.LOGS to append lines in it.

Here is my minimal code:

```
import pandas as pd

class Block:
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger
        
    def check(self):
        self.writeLog('test!')
        
    def writeLog(self, message):
        self.logger = self.logger.append({'Date':10, 'Message':message, 'uid':11}, ignore_index=True)


class Strategy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.LOGS = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Message', 'uid'])
        
        self.blk1 = Block(logger=self.LOGS)
        self.blk2 = Block(logger=self.LOGS)
        
    def nxt(self):
        self.blk1.check()
        self.blk2.check()   
       
        
strat = Strategy()

for i in range(0,5):
    strat.nxt()
    
print(strat.LOGS)

print(strat.blk1.logger)
print(strat.blk2.logger)
```

These are the outputs:

```
>>Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Message, uid]
Index: []

>>  Date Message uid
0   10   test!  11
1   10   test!  11
2   10   test!  11
3   10   test!  11
4   10   test!  11

>>  Date Message uid
0   10   test!  11
1   10   test!  11
2   10   test!  11
3   10   test!  11
4   10   test!  11
```

I don't understand why the attribute LOGS of Strategy is not appended.
I thought I was pointing into strat.LOGS by writing logger=self.LOGS.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

[pandas.DataFrame.append documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

*pandas.DataFrame.append ... returns a new object*

It is also the reason why `strat.blk1.logger` and `strat.blk2.logger` are different

Your code with some debugging modifications

```
import pandas as pd

class Block:
    uid = 0
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger
        
    def check(self):
        self.writeLog('test!')
        
    def writeLog(self, message):
        Block.uid += 1
        self.logger = self.logger.append({'Date':10, 'Message':message, 'uid':Block.uid}, ignore_index=True)


class Strategy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.LOGS = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Message', 'uid'])
        
        self.blk1 = Block(self.LOGS)
        self.blk2 = Block(self.LOGS)
        
    def nxt(self):
        self.blk1.check()
        self.blk2.check()   

strat = Strategy()

print("BEFORE\n")
print('strat.LOGS\n', strat.LOGS, '\n')
print('id()', id(strat.LOGS), '\n')
print('strat.blk1.logger\n', 'id', id(strat.blk1.logger), '\n',strat.blk1.logger, '\n')
print('strat.blk2.logger\n', 'id', id(strat.blk2.logger), '\n', strat.blk2.logger, '\n')      

for i in range(0,5):
    strat.nxt()
    
print("\n\nAFTER\n")
print('strat.LOGS\n', strat.LOGS, '\n')
print('id(strat.LOGS)', id(strat.LOGS), '\n')
print('strat.blk1.logger\n', 'id', id(strat.blk1.logger), '\n',strat.blk1.logger, '\n')
print('strat.blk2.logger\n', 'id', id(strat.blk2.logger), '\n', strat.blk2.logger, '\n')
```

gives

```
BEFORE

strat.LOGS
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Message, uid]
Index: [] 

id() 140039061035088 

strat.blk1.logger
 id 140039061035088 
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Message, uid]
Index: [] 

strat.blk2.logger
 id 140039061035088 
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Message, uid]
Index: [] 



AFTER

strat.LOGS
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Message, uid]
Index: [] 

id(strat.LOGS) 140039061035088 

strat.blk1.logger
 id 140039063529168 
   Date Message uid
0   10   test!   1
1   10   test!   3
2   10   test!   5
3   10   test!   7
4   10   test!   9 

strat.blk2.logger
 id 140039062432592 
   Date Message uid
0   10   test!   2
1   10   test!   4
2   10   test!   6
3   10   test!   8
4   10   test!  10
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because `DataFrame.append` returns a new object every time. See pandas documentation on append [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

In general pandas prefers immutable (stateless) objects, instead of modifying objects in-place. Because of this, I would recommend changing the code a little bit so that each `Block` has its own logger. This is good protection in case of multithreading as well. Then you can create a `get_log` method in `Strategy` that will let you grab the current instance of both `blk.logger` variables. Any sorting by date can happen here as well if needed.

```
import pandas as pd

class Block:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Message', 'uid'])
        
    def check(self):
        self.writeLog('test!')
        
    def writeLog(self, message):
        self.logger = self.logger.append({'Date':10, 'Message':message, 'uid':11}, ignore_index=True)


class Strategy:
    def __init__(self):
       
        self.blk1 = Block()
        self.blk2 = Block()
        
    def nxt(self):
        self.blk1.check()
        self.blk2.check()   
        
    def get_log(self):
        return pd.concat((self.blk1.logger, self.blk2.logger), ignore_index=True)
       
        
strat = Strategy()

for i in range(0,5):
    strat.nxt()
    
print(strat.get_log())

print(strat.blk1.logger)
print(strat.blk2.logger)
```

Output

```
  Date Message uid
0   10   test!  11
1   10   test!  11
2   10   test!  11
3   10   test!  11
4   10   test!  11
5   10   test!  11
6   10   test!  11
7   10   test!  11
8   10   test!  11
9   10   test!  11
  Date Message uid
0   10   test!  11
1   10   test!  11
2   10   test!  11
3   10   test!  11
4   10   test!  11
  Date Message uid
0   10   test!  11
1   10   test!  11
2   10   test!  11
3   10   test!  11
4   10   test!  11
```